# TextView text is not centred

Tags: alignment, android-linearlayout, textview, android

I am trying to centre some code in my text view but it seems to be persistently left aligned:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myButtons">    

<!-- Text -->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:text="Test"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- And the thumbnail -->
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image" 
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_text"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />      
</LinearLayout>
```

The image (when there is one, sometimes it is set to Visibility.GONE) is centre aligned okay. It's just I can't get the text to centre align.

Any thoughts welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I replied under your answer :)

Comment: I have edited my answer take a look

Comment: LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is deprecated according to Eclipse. Is is still safe to use?

Comment: change to LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: I tried doing as you suggest, it ALMOST worked! Here is a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/5h8wo4mqx/ - as you can see, if there is no image then the text does fill the parent and aligns in the middle correctly. If there IS an image, then it all falls apart for some reason. Do you know what could be causing it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add `android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` in your textview attribute to make the center

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

to make the Textview fillParent after imageview is gone

set height of the textview fill_parent Programatically like

```
textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0));
                                          ^                            ^
                                          height                      width
```

Comment: Thanks user2675669, that makes it horizontally centre aligned which is further than I got so thank you! Just one thing though, in the case where the the image view is hidden (Visibility.GONE), how do I get the text view to take up all the available space? Because now, instead of centre aligning vertically, it's top aligning (presumably because it's set to wrap content while the image is fill parent?). Any ideas appreciated, thanks!